# Why did Joshua bring back the king of Ai only to hang him?

Tags: joshua

Why did Joshua bring back the king of Ai only to kill him?  Joshua 8:29

Answer (score 0):

God had given instructions to Joshua regarding Ai's king.

> And thou shalt do to Ai and her king as thou didst unto Jericho and
> her king: only the spoil thereof, and the cattle thereof, shall ye
> take for a prey unto yourselves: lay thee an ambush for the city
> behind it. (Joshua 8:2, KJV)

During the conquest of Ai, an ambush was set against the armies of the city which burned the city after the men had pursued the apparently retreating main front of the Israelite line.  Once the smoke of the city was rising, the ambush came out of the city and struck the men of Ai from behind.  In the process, they took Ai's king captive--a common custom of those days.

> And the king of Ai they took alive, and brought him to Joshua. (Joshua
> 8:23, KJV)

But Joshua was still holding up his spear in battle, and did not relent from his primary purpose to deal with Ai's king at that moment.

> For Joshua drew not his hand back, wherewith he stretched out the
> spear, until he had utterly destroyed all the inhabitants of Ai.
> (Joshua 8:26, KJV)

Once all of the inhabitants of Ai had perished, then it was that its king was dealt with.  However, this was done at the gates of the city.  No mention is made of "returning" with the king from Ai to the camp of Israel.  Remember, Israel did not at this time live in a city.  The "city" mentioned here can only be Ai itself.

> And the king of Ai he hanged on a tree until eventide: and as soon as
> the sun was down, Joshua commanded that they should take his carcass
> down from the tree, and cast it at the entering of the gate of the
> city, and raise thereon a great heap of stones, that remaineth unto
> this day. (Joshua 8:29, KJV)

That "great heap of stones" was built near the gate of the now-destroyed Ai.

Whether or not this was related to the culture of that time, it is interesting that in at least some Asian cultures it was once prohibited for non-royalty to touch royalty, even that of an enemy nation.  For example, a Thai king and a Burmese king could battle each other from their elephants, but their footsoldiers could not intervene, nor strike the enemy monarch themselves.  Only a king could fight a king.  (One might assume that in such a culture, the king would not engage battle himself with the footsoldiers either.)  In any case, Joshua, the representative of Israel's Leader, gave direct orders for the king's death.